# Firefox: How do you get your Menu back after you hide everything?

Tags: firefox

I've hidden everything on my firefox browser (menu, Toolbar, etc) so that i only have the browser window.  Unfortunately, I don't know how to get them back.  I've done right click on the title bar, the Tab, nothing.  Any idea on how to restore it?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hit the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key.  This will open the normal Firefox menu.

Answer (score 6):

Alt-v will bring up the view menu where you can reenable your menu.